# Any multi-thread concern on memcpy function?

Tags: c, multithreading

```
memcpy(a, b, sizeof(a));
```

v.s.

```
a[0] = b[0];
a[1] = b[1];
...
```

Suppose that `memcpy` should have smaller code size and high efficiency, but is there any risk to `memcpy` in multi-thread system?

Comment: I'm not sure why you believe that the alternative to `memcpy()` you propose in the question is any safer as far as threading is concerned (or even why there would be any benefits aside from threading).

Comment: Lets keep in mind that memcpy() is logically equivalent to (for int i=0; i<numBytes; i++) dst[i] = src[i];   ... so anything true about the for-loop will be true about the memcpy() call as well.

Comment: Thanks! Then memcpy is a better solution for this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. If the buffers are exclusive, meaning that threads are not competing for access to the data involved in the copying, then `memcpy` is perfectly safe to use in multi-threaded environment. The function has no persistent state and no other side-effects besides modifying the target buffer.
2. Also, you can safely perform muti-threaded copying *from* a buffer shared by any number of threads, as long as no thread attempts to change that buffer.
3. But once there's a competition between the threads for *writing* into any shared buffers, `memcpy` no longer guarantees thread safety, i.e. the operation is not atomic. Aside from what is described in 2, two simultaneous `memcpy`s operating on the same buffer will interfere with each other and produce unpredictable results.

Comment: I believe that the answer should be that `memcpy()` has nothing to do when it comes to worrying about race conditions, and that of course if one happens things will go bad either with `memcpy()` or assigning each value. Your answer is very close to that though.

Comment: It should be noted for the OP's benefit that the alternate proposed in the question, `a[0]=b[0]; a[1]=b[1]; ...`, has exactly the same properties/concerns as `memcpy()` as far as thread safety goes.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use lock to ensure exclusive, using `memcpy()` only will be very dangerous! The `memcpy()` is only responsible for copying memory, don't ensure thread safe, you should add lock by yourself. In C language, in user's space, you can use `mutex` for ensuring exclusive.

Comment: Thanks! If `a` and `b` are only used in this thread, not shared memory, it that safe to use `memcpy `without `mutex` protection? In this case, can `memcpy` also perform the same function as line by line assignment. I think though it is interrupted in middle of copy, but it should resume the copy task after return from the interrupt.

Comment: @Tmx Assume that there are two threads: A and B. If `a` and `b` belong to A or B, user `memcpy` only or another way you have said will be safety, because there is no any exclusive behavior.  But if `a` and `b` is common,  either way you have said is not safe, because if you do not use `mutex`, you can not ensure the value of `a` and `b`. It is not thread safe. Do you agree with me?

Comment: @cwfighter - your answer is absolutely correct.  I don't know why you were marked down :(  Specifically: 1) Yes, if it's possible for any other thread to access the buffer represented by "a" during the data copy, it must be locked.  2) If there's no chance "a" can be accessed concurrently, then a lock isn't necessary.  3) In theory, "memcpy()", a series of "a[x] = b[x]" instructions, or a "for()" loop should all be equivalent.  In practice, I would almost always recommend "memcpy()".

Answer (score 0):

#### Long story short:

Both code is the same to the compiler, and even compiles exactly to [the same assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/KKznhPece) at optimization level `clang -O1`, `gcc -O2` or higher.

#### Explanation:

Modern C doesn’t enforce “sequentially consistent ordering”, which allows certain reordering to happen:

1. The compiler can freely swap the order of `a[0] = b[0];` and `a[1] = b[1];` if the compiler knows `abs(a - b) ≥ sizeof a / sizeof a[0]`.
2. Even if the compiler doesn’t do that, the CPU can freely swap the order of them as well.
3. Even if the CPU successfully writes data to the memory, another thread may not read the latest copy of that data.

If you want to prevent 1 from happening, you need to insert a compiler fence (e.g., `asm("" ::: "memory");`.

Similarly, if you want to prevent 2 and 3 from happening, you need to insert a memory fence (e.g., `atomic_thread_fence`) or use a mutex which produces an appropriate memory fence whenever you lock or unlock it.

Observing the side-effects of any non-atomic operation from another thread without an appropriate synchronization mechanism is undefined behavior.

Based on the above assumptions, the compiler can freely make these two transformations:

1. Transform your whole `a[0] = b[0]; …` sequence into a `memcpy`, if the compiler knows `a` and `b` doesn’t overlap.
2. Transform your whole `a[0] = b[0]; …` sequence into a `memmove`, if the compiler knows `a ≤ b`.
3. Transform your whole `a[0] = b[0]; …` sequence into some SIMD instructions so both statements are executed in parallel, if the compiler knows `a` and `b` doesn’t overlap within the distance of a SIMD vector length.
4. Similarly, the compiler can also do the transformation in reverse if `sizeof a` is small.

Therefore, to the compiler, there is no difference. No matter whether your program is single-threaded or multi-threaded.